# Can I link to all sites from within each site in my collection

Tags: site-collection, top-link-bar, links-list

At the moment when I land on the site root (SharePoint homepage) I see a list of all sub sites displayed in the top links bar.

When I click on a particular site, the top menu bar is replaced with the top menu links bar for that site. This means in order to view all sites again it's necessary to return to the site root first.

Is there a way to insert a list of links to all sub sites into *each* sub site? This could appear beneath the Navigation left menu, or the top menu. I'm aware I could accomplish this by manually inserting all links into each site, but I'd like to avoid doing this if at all possible!

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the site setting 'Inherits top navigation from parent site' to keep the same top-nav in all your subsites. It's an option when you create a new site, you you should find it under Site Settings > Look and Feel > Navigation or similar (it varies a little in publishing sites)

Comment: In my install the route was: 'Site Actions' > 'Site Settings' > (Look and Feel section) 'Top link bar' > 'Use Links from Parent'

Answer (score 0):

First at all you should activate Publishing feature on the site that should inherit navigation. This feature activates Navigation link of Look and feel section in site settings page. The navigation settings page contains 'Inherits top navigation from parent site' option.

Other way is you can add links to the sites by hand (site settings -> look and feel -> top link bar) :)